Azure APIM liquid transformation from JSON to XML not working with for loop
I'm currently experiencing an issue similar to the one described in the following thread and could really use some assistance -
Azure API Management policy for loop not working on array
I have implemented the exact solution implemented, but the template still does not read the array of values.
Here is my transformation code.
<json-to-xml apply="always" consider-accept-header="true" parse-date="true" />
<set-body template="liquid">
    <soapenv:Envelope >
        <soapenv:Body>
            <Create xmlns="http://siebel.com/WebService">
                <SharedList>
                    {% for item in body.sharedList.contact %}
                        <contact>
                            {% if item.userId %}
                            <UserId>{{item.userId}}</UserId>
                            {% else %}
                            <UserId>Empty</UserId>
                            {% endif %}
                        </contact>
                    {% endfor %}
                </SharedList>
                <AssetNum>{{body.Document.AssetNum}}</AssetNum>
            </CreateSR_Input>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</set-body>
<!-- Set Content-Type header to XML -->
<set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
    <value>application/xml</value>
</set-header>

I appreciate any suggestions.
Here is the sample payload.
{
 "assetNum": "",
 "sharedList": {
    "contact": [
            {
            "userId": "spokuri"
            }
        ]
    }
}


You need to modify the policy and add the Content-Type to application/json before initiating liquid transformation as suggested by @Markus Meyer in the SO.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body template="liquid">
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <Create xmlns="http://siebel.com/WebService">
                        <SharedList>
                            {% for item in body.sharedList.contact %}
                            <contact>
                                {% if item.userId %}
                                <UserId>{{item.userId}}</UserId>
                                    {% else %}
                                <UserId>Empty</UserId>
                                {% endif %}
                            </contact>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </SharedList>
                        <AssetNum>{{body.Document.AssetNum}}</AssetNum>
                    </Create>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </set-body>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/xml</value>
        </set-header>
    </inbound>
</policies>

This will give you expected response.


